# rails time discrepancy in generating response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and for one request, it takes 86 ms:

```
Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

It's hosted on local host. It takes 4.1 seconds, so where is it spending the rest 82ms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The time is accounted for as Views, Database/ActiveRecord and (not shown) Processing Time (controllers/models). The latter is what you aren't seeing in the log.

You can demonstrate this by checking the times for an action, then adding `sleep 10` (10 second pause) to the controller then check the times again, the Views and Database times will be similar but overall time will be 10 seconds longer.